# Ordering specific column inside p:dataTable based on argument

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datacolumn

I have to show data from `Student` table in a `<p:dataTable>` which looks like as follows:

```
<p:dataTable
    value="#{school.getStudent(GENDER)}"
    var="student" />
    ......all <p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Here, `school.getStudent(MALE)` will return a list of all male students and `school.getStudent(FEMALE)` will return a list of all female students.

Now the problem what I am facing is ordering the data.
The requirement is:

- If it is `MALE`, order based on `ID`
- If it is `FEMALE`, order based on `NAME`

`ID` and `NAME` are columns of the `Student` table.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Wrong question. You should do it in SQL (JPA/JDBC), not in JSF. So, you'd need to reframe your question to remove all irrelevant JSF noise and show the DB interaction code behind `getStudent()` instead.

Comment: I agree with you that we should remove all JSF Noise, but why can't I create a comparator to compare two Student object based on different Parameters? The comparators will be a static inner class inside the entity and I will call these comparators with Collections.sort(List, <Comparator_Name>); from my bean.

Answer (score 3):

Do it in your backing bean. Sort your Collection that you are going to display before returning it. Primefaces will display the entries in the table in the order that the Collection provides the entries. So use an `ArrayList` to keep the order and use a Comparator together with `Collections.sort(...)` to sort the List.

Might look like this:

```
public List<Student> getStudent(Gender gender) {
    Comparator<Student> comparator;
    if (gender == Gender.MALE) {
        comparator = new MaleStudentComparator();
    }
    else {
        comparator = new FemaleStudentComparator();
    }

    return Collections.sort(studentList, comparator);
}
```

Comment: I am following your approach and data is coming correctly. I have written two comparators. The comparators are static inner class inside my entity and I am calling them with Collections.sort(List, <Comparator_Name>); from my bean.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <p:column sortBy=#{bean.gender ? widgetVar.Name : widgetVar.id}>
```

Let assume bean.gender is a boolean value which returns "True" in case of female and "False" in case of "Male".